# Angular 4 - ERROR in ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat

Tags: angular, typescript

I am developing an application with **`Angular4`**. I have to change my laptop, organize the environment in my new machine and run the project. I'm getting an error when running the command:

```
ng serve
```

When I run it and get to 13%, I get the following error:

> ERROR in ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'E:\E\Dev_Teradata\Davivienda\Front\conciliaciones-covalent-angular\src\app\app.module.ts'

I understand that you can not find the file **`"app.module.ts"`** in the path that is showing me the error because it marks **`"E:\E\"`**, when it should be **`"E:\Dev_Teradata\Davivienda\Front\conciliaciones-covalent- angular\src\app\app.module.ts "`**

I thank you very much for your collaboration and/or guidance to help solve this problem!

[image: Description Link]

Comment: can you show the inclusion of the `app.module.ts` in the referencing file ? It might have to do with the manner in which you are `importing`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround**

Please change file \src\app\index.ts from this

```
export { AppModule } from './app.module';
```

to this

```
export * from './app.module';
```

Looks like a [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1695) in angular CLI

Comment: Hi @Pandiyan, I have made the change you propose and this has worked correctly, I have also looked at the link that you passed me and I understand that it would be a problem with the Angular Cli. I appreciate your collaboration.
you have a good day.